# Define position for signature (Sign here) in bulk send docusign

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm working with DocuSign and it pretty good for now. For a single email, I can define the Sign here parameter and it will be shown exactly the place where I wanna sign. But for bulk send, I do the same with the parameter but there is no fixed signature, I have to drag and drop the sign place.

So my question is can we make the signature fixed for bulk send?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the Bulk Send feature from DocuSign (please show your code if otherwise) then the initial envelope you set is copied many times for each send. The tag, if placed correctly on the first envelope, would be copied to each of the envelopes you send.

Comment: let assume I have two signature must be signed, and wanna it's fixed at two corners at the bottom of last page... I tried SignHere prop the same with sending individual recipient but not correct.

Comment: which prop I should use, could you provide me the link to and sample.. in the sample bulk send of DocuSign it doesn't define sign here

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/bulk-sending-envelopes this is in seven languages. Hope this helps.